# What is the bedroom section of a master bedroom with foyer called?

Tags: bedroom, terminology

Is there a particular term used for the section of a master bedroom that has the bed, if there is an adjoining foyer that is also part of the master bedroom?

```
 (Master bedroom)
+---------------+
|     *****     |
|     *BED*     |
|     *   *     |
|     *****     |
|               |
|     (???)     |
|               |
+-----     -----+
|               |
|     (Foyer)   |
|               |
|               |
+------===------+
```

I was thinking "sleeping area", "bed area", but I was wondering if there is a more standard way of referring to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called "Master Bedroom".  In your diagram, it's part of a "Master Suite", consisting of a foyer and a bedroom.

Answer (score 4):

If the door to the suite is in the foyer section, it could also be called the **antechamber**.  That would make the bed section the main chamber or **bedchamber**.

...and of course, no discussion of chambers should ignore the chamberpot  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Larger room is "bedroom" and the foyer/other is commonly called "sitting room or area"